# Install4j 32 bit and 64 bit default install directories

Tags: java, windows, install4j

I have an application that is 32 bit and I want to offer a 64 bit version.

When installing 64 bit, I do not want it remember the install location of the 32 bit 'C:\Program Files (x86)' and for the 32 bit I don't want it to remember install location for 64 bit.

For example, if install 64 bit and 32 bit already istalled, I want it to ignore the 32 bit install location. However if the 64 bit is already installed, I want it to remember the install location.

Comment: this question belongs to superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything for that, for 32-bit installers, the previous locations are stored in the Wow6432Node nodes. They do not interfere with the 64-bit values.

Comment: I used version 5 to build. I ran my 64 bit installer. Then I run my 32 bit installer and it points to C:\Program Files\ instead of C:\Program Files (x86)

Comment: This is fixed in the latest version